# Gulp - how to include a newly created file in a task

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp task which creates a JSON file from a YAML file and I want to use this JSON file in another task. But when I include this JSON file in the second task it says `Error: Cannot find module './public/index.json'`. I can see that the file is generated succesfully and if I run gulp for the second time it won't return any error. Why is this so and how can I correct it so that everything works fine in the first run?

Here's how the code looks like:

```
var yaml = require('gulp-yaml');

gulp.task('GenerateJSON', function() {
  gulp.src("public/index.yaml")
    .pipe(yaml())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'))
});

gulp.task('GenerateIndex', function() {
    var foo = require('./public/index.json');
    ...
});
```

And yes, I'm using `run-sequence` plugin, that's not helping either. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the same result if you make the 'Index' task dependent on the 'JSON' task like gulp.task('GenerateIndex', ['G nereateJSON'], function() and just call GenerateIndex?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I already tried that and it isn't working :(

Comment: Could you use something like var fileContent = fs.readFileSync("./public/index.jsong", "utf8");  instead of the require .json call to see if it helps?

Comment: @Mark Sorry, that didn't work too, same error.

Comment: Edit: I posted a working code which was different from the erroneous code I had in my project. Question edited so that the accepted answer makes sense and may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue. The GenerateJSON was not successfully terminating.

Adding, a return statement solved the issue.

Comment: Was the original post edited to add a return statement?  It does indicate an edit?

Comment: @Mark I'm extremely sorry, the code in the question is different from the actual code I used in the project in order to make it simpler. i.e. I combined two functions into one (GenerateJSON) and the second function missed the return statement. SpEcHiDe was able to spot it because he's working with me on the same project. Apologies once again.

Comment: I think I should edit the question so that it'll help others.